# SSRS для нескольких наборов отчетов

Tags: ssrs

Можно ли использовать один и тот же SSRS для нескольких наборов отчетов.
Т.е. иметь более одного набора ролей\пользователей\прав и отчетов, и соответственно, несколько порталов на одном сервере?